# Getting the list of the latests posts and custom type posts in the homepage

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

When I need to get a single post type list I usually use `get_posts`, how can I retrieve multiple `custom posts types` to populate the site homepage?

To be more precise, I would like to get the latest mixed posts (so mixed slugs like work, photo, code) and oreder them by date.

I could call `get_posts` per each custom post type and then filter them, but I was just wondering if there was a more optimized way to do it, something like:

```
<?php
$args = array (
    'post_type' => array ('work', 'photo', 'code', 'post'),
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$posts_array = get_posts($args);
?>
```

So, does exists some way to get a mixed post type list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post_type` argument of the `get_posts()` function is for retrieving different types of post content. I'm assuming here that 'work', 'photo', and 'code' are custom post types.

## Grabbing multiple post types with WP_Query

Instead of using `get_posts()`, you can use the `WP_Query` class to grab multiple post types. I just tested the following on my local install:

```
<?php

$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('event', 'post')
));

while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

?>

// ... the loop goes here as usual
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This grabbed posts of type "event" and of type "post" for me and displayed them by date. [You can learn a lot more about the WP_Query object on the codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). There's even a [section specific to querying types and parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters).

Note that you do need to reference the object returned when instantiating the `WP_Query` object at the top of the loop with something like `$q->`, but you don't need to do this inside of the loop.

Comment: perfect! this is exactly what I was looking for.